# How to uncheck "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" checkbox from the API

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

[image]

I have tried use the `azure-devops-node-api` node package and the REST API to programmatically uncheck the 'Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here' check box.

I have used git diff to compare the network response on this page with the check box checked and not checked and the property doesn't seem to be included in the build definition.

Any ideas how to structure the build definition to leave this checkbox unchecked?

I have left the triggers array empty, I have explored build options that may be relevant, I have tried using a single trigger with trigger type None...

Comment: The pipeline yaml definition now supports disabling all triggers with `trigger: none`, however that doesn't directly address the question.

Comment: I need this too in the c# api, ive tried everything!